# How can I convert a Point to pixel coordinates?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

To get the global screen position (in pixels!) of some [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) I'm calling [`DisplayObject::localToGlobal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29) like

```
var o: DisplayObject = ...;
var topLeft: Point = o.localToGlobal( new Point( 0, 0 ) );
```

I noticed that every now and then I'm getting double values for `topLeft.y`, even though I expected some integer value. Is there some scaling or coordinate system I have to take into account?

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to transformations applied to the parents of your `DisplayObject`.

You can find out all the transformations affecting a `DisplayObject` using:

```
myDisplayObject.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
```

This is the results of all transformations applied to your target and its parents up to the root of the display list.

[More info.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Transform.html#concatenatedMatrix)

Answer (score 0):

`x`/`y` coordinates and `width`/`height` are floating point values in Flash. It is perfectly legal to  size/position objects with sub-pixel values (ie: non-integer values).

With respect to scaling, you can query the objects `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties to see if they are being scaled, or force these values to 1.

Comment: Ok, so how *do* I convert sub-pixel values to pixel values - just multiply by scaleX/scaleY and then round up to the next integer value (considering 'partially' covered pixels as totally covered)? It seems suspicious that I have to do this myself... I can't shake the feeling that there must be some transformation matrix or the like to do this for me.

Comment: When working with objects on the display list, I don't bother converting `x`/`y`/`width`/`height` to integers. Flash player deals with sub pixels (twips?) just fine. If I need an int, I either cast it to int (fastest), or use the `Math` functions (round/floor/ceil) if I need control of the rounding.

Comment: The issue is that these coordinates will be used by another process (which receives the data via a socket) - that other process expects to receive global coordinates in pixels. So unfortunately I have to do this myself. :-/